# can i make an equivalent to /* and */ for comment blocks?

Tags: objective-c

Its driving me crazy, I spend soo much time getting it wrong, and then fixing it wrong.

I'm thinking  of using -= and =- as delineators, but it probably means a lot of hours in learning how to fool the compiler into a substitution. Is this a quixotic quest? can such be done? has it been done already, albeit with different keystrokes?

I work alone. I don't collaborate.
So I don't mind a non-standard work environment

If I need to in the future i could make a scheme whereby both could work.

Comment: I don't like wearing shoes, so let's carpet over the entire world.

Comment: No can do, without either installing your own preprocessor in the build process or writing your own compiler.  (A little curious as to what problem you have with the standard delimiters that would be solved by a different set.)

Comment: you can write some script preprocess the source before feed it to the compiler.

Comment: i don't mind walking barefoot, why do i have to walk over the broken glass path simply because some geezer in the 70's did? see also last edit below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without building your own custom version of the preprocessor. Comment syntax is an inherent part of the language and is not designed to be configurable.

(Incidentally, `-=` is already a token in Objective-C — it means "assign to LHS the result of subtracting RHS from LHS.")

Comment: Oh. so that's that then. On a full size keyboard its just a twiddle over in the numbepad area, but on a laptop, its a pain.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to extend `clang`, then modify your Xcode builds to include your `clang` extensions. I have no personal experience with writing complier extension for `clang`, but I did work on a tool that extended `cl.exe`. **Warning**: this would be a *very* deep dive into the internals of the build system.

[Extending Clang](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/Gregor_ExtendingClang.pdf)

Good Luck

Comment: see last comment below.